# Does my question still need revision?

Tags: support

I asked the question "[Why does Nietzsche think pain has value?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/61935/29944)" and cited a quote from *The Gay Science*. I have edited the title to narrow the object to just psychic pain. As well, I have added a furtherance of my question, specifically noting my inability to understand Nietzsche's rationale for considering suffering as something great, or, as I believe is equivocal, why pain is of value.

The question has received up votes since the edit, while it has been on hold, so that leads me to believe I am on the appropriate track. My question here is what else does my post need to be taken off this hold?

Comment: Surely there is a clear distinction between my post and some of the other relatively recent posts that are on hold? I could accept it not being a philosophical question (though I'm pretty sure it is), but I would appreciate that being shown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, I up-voted your question and voted to re-open it. I was hoping to answer it when I got a chance.

Bottom line, Nietzsche's view appears to be that pain, not pleasure, makes us struggle to improve ourselves. (See paragraph 225 of *Beyond Good and Evil*.) However, I can easily imagine that too much suffering could kill us which wouldn't lead to much of an improvement.

Regarding the closed question, it only takes five users with enough reputation to vote to close a question. Don't give up. Keep trying with other questions. Welcome.

Comment: Thank you. Though the thought is appreciated, I think the position of my concern is outside that of a Q&A forums and beckons for too much novel philosophizing. Disappointed, but I suppose I am not surprised. Godel knows I need find no answer.

Comment: Might I add just for the sake of record; I feel just as disparagingly about civilization as ever. Nietzsche has not weakened my hatred for most of man.

Comment: i guess.. that you seem to be asking for justification (difficult with nietzsche) or consolation (more still) rather than an explanation ? @MattWatson

Comment: Yes I would be looking for justification.

Answer (score 1):

Well considering your question title asks about "psychic pain", something which is not a common term (what is it, the pain caused by the occult? By mediums and psychics?) and which you don't define, and which your quote from Nietzsche does not mention, yes, I'd say your question still needs substantial revisions.

Please do not ask "why" Nietzsche said something without clearly providing a quote where he said it.

Comment: Pain of the psyche is unclear? Asininity

Comment: @MattWatson: Pain is a purely psychological phenomenon, so yes, pain of the psyche is indeed unclear.

Comment: Thank you Philip, noted. My thinking in adding the adjective was someone considering physical traumatic pain, but I can see how your statement is correct.